# How to interpret the indptr in networkx.adjacency_matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I'm using the `networkx` in `python`. I tested the function `adjacency_matrix` but I could not understand some of the results. For example:

```
import networkx as nx 
import numpy as np

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
g.add_edges_from([[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]])
adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(g)
print adj.todense()
# [[0 1 1]
#  [1 0 1]
#  [1 1 0]]
print adj.__dict__
# {'indices': array([1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]), 'indptr': array([0, 2, 4, 6]), 'maxprint'
# : 50, '_shape': (3, 3), 'data': array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])}
```

In the result of `print adj.__dict__`, what does the `indices` and `indptr` stand for? I think they are the key information that is used to reconstruct the adjacency matrix, together with the `data` attribute. But I cannot figure out how it is achieved.

Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: `adjacency_matrix` returns a scipy sparse matrix.  So `adj` is a scipy sparse matrix.  I don't know much about them, but I've added scipy to your tags since this is a question about properties of a scipy object.

Comment: @Joel Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adj` which is given by `nx.adjacency_matrix` is a [compressed sparse row](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29) matrix format of your adjacency matrix.

A compressed format,

> represents a matrix M by three (one-dimensional) arrays, that respectively contain [the] nonzero values, the extents of rows, and column indices.

In your case `adj.indices` is a one-dimensional (numpy) array with the indices of the nonzero values of the adjacency matrix. Together with `adj.indptr` you can know the exact location of nonzero values in your matrix. By definition `adj.indptr[0] == 0`, and `adj.indptr[i] == adj.indptr[i-1] + number of nonzero values at row i`. The `data` attribute refers to the nonzero values, in your case they are all 1's.